# Set data attribute on all elements in array but this element

Tags: jquery, html, this

This is my markup

```
<div class="parent">
  <img data-position="1" src="">
  <img data-position="2" src="">
  <img data-position="3" src="">
  <img data-position="4" src="">
</div>
```

When any of the `img` elements clicked, the clicked element needs to have its `data-position` set to `1` and the rest of elements should follow with `data-position="2"` and so on. To achieve this I can't append or rearrange elements, since this will have no effect.

This is what I have tried. I thought, why not get all them `not(this)` elements put the through the loop and assign data attributes.

```
var img = $('img')
img.on('click', function() {
    var otherElements = img.not(this).length;
    console.log(otherElements)
});
```

This piece of code works right the first time, but on the second lick I get different results.

Comment: I don't see where you're doing any assignment of a `data-position` value. You're just looping.

Comment: Do you want to renumber everything, or is it enough to just swap the current number one to be the one clicked.

Comment: While looping, the first time around I get 3 (which is correct), then if I click one more time I get 2, which is not correct.

Comment: @Taplar, yes I need to renumber everything.

Comment: Do the numbers need to wrap? Like is the first element going to get data-position=4 of the first click is elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the `not(this)` as you showed originally, and then update the data-position on them.  Then update the data-position on the one clicked, at some point, to 1.

```js
var $images = $('img').on('click', function(){
  $images.not(this).attr('data-position', function(index){
    return index + 2;
  });
  
  $(this).attr('data-position', 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <img data-position="1" src="" alt="one">
  <img data-position="2" src="" alt="two">
  <img data-position="3" src="" alt="three">
  <img data-position="4" src="" alt="four">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yam1hox6/1/

Here's the important code:

```
var imgs = $('div.parent > img')
imgs.on('click', function(index) {
    $(this).attr("data-position", "1");
    var otherElements = imgs.not(this);
    otherElements.each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("data-position", index+2);
    })

    // Optionally, uncomment the next 3 lines to output the data-positions
    //$(imgs).each(function(index) {
    //  console.log(index, $(this).attr("data-position"));
    //});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution involves setting the event listener on the parent so that it's easier to query and manipulate its children. The elements that came before the clicked target will 'wrap' and continue the numbering from where the last element in the array left of.

```
const $parent = $('.parent');
const $children = $parent.children();
const childrenLength = $children.length;
$parent.on('click', e => {
  const clickedIndex = $children.index(e.target);
  let rearange = 1;
  $children.each((i, el) => {
    if (i < clickedIndex) {
      el.dataset.position = (childrenLength - clickedIndex + 1) + i;
    } else {
      el.dataset.position = rearange++;
    }
  });
});
```

Running example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt8r10uw/)